# Can't get last output of a multidimensional-array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i'm making this small Music Array (multidimensional), but i can't manage to get the "price" as a output. (Output with a printarray that shows all the prices under eachother.

This script works on a single array (Non-multidimensional).

I tried:

Implode, Printarray, keys.. items etc..

Code:

```
    <?php

$Music = array (
    array("title"=> "Versace On The Floor", "singer"=> "Bruno Mars", "genre" => "pop", "price"=> 1.99),
    array("title"=> "Roar", "singer"=> "Katy Pery", "genre" => "pop", "price"=> 2.50),
    array("title"=> "Warriors", "singer"=> "Imagine Dragons", "genre" => "pop", "price"=> 2.30)
);

echo "<br>";

$x = count($Music);

foreach($Music as $row)
{
    if($x ==1)
    { $secondLast = $row;}
    $x--; 
}
echo $secondLast;

?>
```

Comment: You have to `echo` the array with the key `echo $secondLast['price'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without loop:

```
echo $Music[count($Music) - 2]['price'];
```

`count($Music) - 2` gives you the index of the second last element. In yor case it is `1` (`3 - 2`)

Similar to this last item can be achieved with:

```
echo $Music[count($Music) - 1]['price'];
```

Comment: If you are using the method be sure to check that you have enough elements in the array.

Comment: Method is called "accessing element of array by it's index".

Answer (score 0):

`$secondLast` is array,

Correct like below

```
echo $secondLast['price'];
```

but what you are printing is last one,not second last

Use

Either

> Note : This is more efficient in current context to get second last element , doesn't matter whether array key is an
>   integer or a string

```
end($Music);
$second_last = prev($Music);
echo $second_last['price'];
```

OR

```
echo $Music[count($Music)-2]['price']
```